# Problem concatenating function with string in client scope variable in Application.cfc

Tags: variables, coldfusion, application.cfc

I want to set a client scope variable which is a combination of text and the output from a function. No matter how I format the cfset I can't get the result I need.

I am using session management and the users are authenticated against database tables. So I use the `GetAuthUser()` function to get the user name.

In my **application.cfc** I want to prefix the username with a pathname string. But I can't seem to get the syntax correct. I always end up with only the string. I start and stop the Coldfusion sever to make sure the client scope is cleared but it makes no difference.

I would prefer to use cfset for this and not cfscript.

This is the function in my **application.cfc**:

```
<cffunction name="OnSessionStart" >

  <cfset client.customerpath="C:\Dropbox\CustomerArea\" & #GetAuthUser()#>

</cffunction>
```

A cfdump shows only `C:\Dropbox\CustomerArea\`

The `GetAuthUser()` on it's own works fine. I just can't seem to prefix it.

Comment: There's code missing from your post.

Comment: What version of CF? What happens if you do output just `#getAuthUser()#` or do a direct string like `C:\Dropbox\CustomerArea\#getAuthUser()#`?

Comment: CF version 2018.If I output #getAuthUser()# then I get the user name fine. I'm not sure how a literal string C:\Dropbox\CustomerArea\#getAuthUser()# would help.

Comment: OK I just realised that the #....# will get interpreted. Thank you very much for your suggestion. It's a great tip and I will use it - even though it didn't resolve this particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

First, verify that your Login is working correctly. I believe that your code above is functioning correctly, but the login is breaking down somewhere, so your `getAuthUser()` is blank.

After that is verified, your above concatenation should work as expected.

Or, there are a couple of other ways to concatenate a string. Off the top of my head:

Your method:

```
<cfset client.s1="C:\Dropbox\CustomerArea\" & GetAuthUser()>
```

Direct concatenation: *(NOTE: In modern versions of CF, this one should be pretty quick for multiple calls.)*

```
<cfset client.s2="C:\Dropbox\CustomerArea\#GetAuthUser()#">
```

The shorthand of your method:

```
<cfset client.s3="C:\Dropbox\CustomerArea\"> 
<cfset client.s3&=GetAuthUser()>
```

And the Java StringBuffer:

```
<cfset client.s4 = createObject("java",  "java.lang.StringBuffer").init("C:\Dropbox\CustomerArea\")>
<cfset client.s4 = client.s4.append(getAuthUser()).toString()>
```

Each method will have different performance, and you will have to test in your system to see which is most performant.

https://trycf.com/gist/22fc36dcbb8653d0b32ceb22987bf2d5/acf?theme=monokai

*NOTE: You might also want to provide a default directory to prevent accidental assignment to a higher directory.  (If CF11+, you can use the elvis operator to make this easy. [https://trycf.com/gist/0b0d513b3e45af427f4813099e84c9c9/acf11?theme=monokai)](https://trycf.com/gist/0b0d513b3e45af427f4813099e84c9c9/acf11?theme=monokai)_)*

---

And on a personal opinion note, I don't know why you would prefer `<cfset...>` over using `cfscript`. This is one of the things that `cfscript` makes exceptionally easy and clear. Plus changing from `cftags` to `cfscript` will open up a lot of benefits to ColdFusion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are absolutely correct about cfscript. The situation is that I have not coded ColdFusion for about 12 years. Or anything else for that matter. So it's like I have to relearn everything and I have found I am confused about when #..# is and is not required. So I have decided to stick with cf tags until I get the hang of it. But yes know I'll end up using cfscript for things like this for the reasons you stated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion and the code examples. It was extremely helpful. You made me realise that I have the user authentication occuring OnRequestStart yet I was trying to set this variable with the user name OnSessionStart. Thus when I examined the user name on the cfm page it was set, but of course when this variable is being set in the application.cfc it has not yet been set. What I had to do is use the session scope.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have `getAuthUser()` just as you are starting the session? Consider this instead:

```
<cffunction name="OnRequestStart" >

   <cfset request.customerpath = "C:\Dropbox\CustomerArea\#GetAuthUser()#">

</cffunction>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and the code example. You helped me realise that I have the user authentication in OnRequestStart but I was trying to set this variable OnSessionStart. I am now setting it in OnRequestStart. I tried your suggestion but I got  "You  have  attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class  java.lang.String as a  structure with members". So instead I used the session scope within OnRequestStart and it works fine.

Comment: Try doing a `<cfdump var="#request#">` . Request scope, to best of my knowledge, always exists.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who replied. You helped me realise that in Applicaiton.cfc I had the user authentication in OnRequestStart but I was trying to use the username in OnSessionStart. I moved the variable assignment to OnRequestStart and I used the session scope for the variable.

```
<cffunction name="OnRequestStart">

<!--- code here including cflogin to authenticate user --->

        <cfif GetAuthUser() NEQ "">
            <cfset session.customerpath="C:\Dropbox\CustomerArea\#GetAuthUser()#">
        <cfelse>
            <cfset session.customerpath="User not authenticated">
        </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

I hope that using the session scope within OnRequestStart is not bad practice. I assume it just means the variable will get reset more often - which I hope is slightly more secure anyway.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, the variable will get reset more often.  It's not the end of the world, but it's unnecessary execution of code.  If your server ever becomes very very busy, it might cause problems.